# Ошибка "Imports are incorrectly sorted and/or formatted " при импортировании модулей Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, импорт

[image: Ошибка]

[image: Код]

Если исправить автоматически - перенесёт весь код ниже на одну строчку (кроме импорта) (третий скриншот)
Пробовал отбить вручную строчки - не вариант, всё равно подсвечивает как ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а текст вместо скриншота что мешает вставить?

Comment: что значит "отбить строчки"? что вы используете для запуска скрипта? 2 строчки - это просто спецификация PEP8

Comment: Наличие ошибки, которую я хотел показать. Текст, если что, есть в заголовке. Но гугл молчит по этому поводу
P.S. Спасибо с двумя строчками. У меня был какой-то баг. Действительно в случае самостоятельного отступления это работает.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/73749897/10562663

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @Dmitry, обратите внимание, что по приведённой мною ссылке ничего не сказано про неуместность картинок как таковых. вот про неуместность выкладывания картинок **вместо** текста — сколько угодно. а **вместе** — да пожалуйста. // да вот в данном конкретном случае автор вопроса **даже сам** в заголовок не смог вписать текст ошибки правильно (я насчитал две грамматические ошибки). а дополнил бы картинки текстом (и, соответственно, просто скопировал бы и вставил текст в заголовок) — грамматических ошибок бы не было. это так, для иллюстрации.

Comment: @Dmitry, по поводу уместности приведённой мною ссылки, надеюсь, у вас вопросов больше нет?

Comment: @Dmitry `ее под каждым вопросом можно вставлять и она везде и всегда будет уместна` — согласен полностью и двумя руками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расширение [isort](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.isort) балуется.

Данная проблема наблюдается после обновления `VSCode`. Если вы не устанавливали его и оно вам не нужно, просто отключите в расширениях

вот здесь нажмите `Disable`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Действительно всё пропало. Спасибо

Comment: @DarkSpace на здоровье)